# Access from Google sheets to Google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple function that creates a folder on google drive. I want to transfer the name to it and run it from the Sheets. But I'm denied access. How to solve this problem without triggers? Thank you

```
function myFunction() {
   var folderName = "SEO";
   var folder=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
   var fileName = "NewFolder";
   var file=SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
   var copyFile=DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
   folder.addFile(copyFile);
   DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);}
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ndfj.png)

Comment: customFunctions must be side effect free, you can add a [menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) and read the name of the folder  from that cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google Apps Script documentation:

> If your custom function throws the error message "You do not have permission to call X service.", the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

The solution is to create a custom menu for your spreadsheet and execute your function upon clicking on the menu item.

```
 function onOpen(){

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Menu')
   .addItem('Menu item', 'yourFunc')
   .addToUi();

    }

 function yourFunc(){

     //your code

   }
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks bro! 
Now we need to comprehend the full depth of google sheets )